# JAX-RS via Jersey -> No Content Returned In HTTP Body (Method Completes Without Errors)

Tags: java, http, jakarta-ee, jersey, jax-rs

I am using JAX-RS via Jersey and I have hit a "bump in the road". I have a method that is supposed to return a JSON object following an HTTP POST. It does execute successfully, but does not return the JSON Object (Unless I do a work around). I am hoping someone can tell me why this does not work as I expect it to. See the following code:

```
@Path("chatroom")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class ChatroomResource {
ChatroomService service = new ChatroomService();
//this works properly and returns the object as json
@GET
public List<Chatroom> getChatrooms() {
    return service.getChatrooms();
}

/**********
 * This works, but does not return any content in response body
 *******/
@POST
public Chatroom addRoom(Chatroom room) {
    return service.addChatroom(room);
    /* 
     * This one does produce content body
     * service.addChatroom(room);
     * return room;
     */

}
}
```

The following Method is in the service object:

```
public Chatroom addChatroom(Chatroom room) {
    return Cache.getChatrooms().put(room.getRoomName(), room);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### What might be wrong and how to fix it

Based on the *superficial* details you've provided, I believe the following instruction is returning `null`:

```java
return Cache.getChatrooms().put(room.getRoomName(), room);
```

In the `put(String, Chatroom)` method, I guess you are adding the `Chatroom` instance to the cache, but you are returning `null` instead of the `Chatroom` instance.

The following should work:

```java
public Chatroom addChatroom(Chatroom room) {
    Cache.getChatrooms().put(room.getRoomName(), room);
    return room;
}
```

### Update 1

As you mentioned in the comments, you are using a [`Hashtable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Hashtable.html) to implement your cache.

Be aware the [`put(K, V)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Hashtable.html#put-K-V-) method returns the **previous** value of the specified key in the hashtable, or `null` if it did not have one. For more details, consider reading the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Hashtable.html).

### Update 2

Have you ever consider using a [`HashMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) instead of a [`Hashtable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Hashtable.html)?

If synchronization becomes an issue, you might be interested in a [`ConcurrentHashMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html).

Comment: I thought the same thing, however i tested with:

    Chatroom test = Cache.getChatrooms().put(string, chatroom);
    return test;

and it works just fine like that

Comment: Is there any more details I could provide that may assist you in assisting me? "Help me help you help me"

Comment: @KurtisDurtis Yes, consider editing your question adding the code of the `put(String, Chatroom)` method.

Comment: .put(String,Chatroom)  is the built in Java HashTable method. I did not write it myself, as it comes with the JDK. The String, Chatroom comes from the table being defined as HashTable<String,Chatroom> chatrooms = new HashTable<>();

Comment: @KurtisDurtis Your update in the question might confuse other users. Could you consider removing that? Also note the last piece of code won't compile because of the `=`.